# Vue.js 2.x Select inside component not getting value

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to remember how to return the value within the select from a component.

Despite I bet is pretty easy I forgot or I am just doing it wrong.

I call the component:

```
<custom-select :options="options" v-model="selectedMain"></custom-select>
```

And then I have the component itself:

```
<template>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <select v-model="selected" 
                id="something" 
                name="something">
            <option :value="null">Select an option</option>
            <option v-for="option in options" 
                    value="option.id"
                    v-html="option.name"></option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</template>
<script>
    module.exports = {
        props: [ 'options' ],
        data: function() {
            return {
                selected: null
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is defined in my main Vue instance of course and it renders ok:

```
new Vue({
    ...
    data: function() {
        return {
            ...
            selectedMain: null
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
})
```

But when I change the value to 1 (for instance) from the dropdown I can see in the Vue Debugger toolbar that:

> ```
> <Root>
>     selectedMain: null
>     <CustomSelect>
>         selected: 1
>     </CustomSelect>
> </Root>
> ```

Edit 1: I think this is pretty the same thing:

```js
Vue.component('custom-select', {
  data () {
    return {
      selected: null
    }
  },
  props: [ 'options' ],
  template: `<fieldset class="form-group">
        <select v-model="selected"
                id="something"
                name="something">
            <option :value="null">Select an option</option>
            <option v-for="option in options"
                    value="option.id"
                    v-html="option.name"></option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      options: [
        { id: 1, name: "First option" },
        { id: 2, name: "Second option" },
        { id: 3, name: "Third option" },
      ],
      selectedMain: null
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <custom-select :options="options" v-model="selectedMain"></custom-select>
  <p>Selected Main: {{ selectedMain }}</p>
</div>
```

Therefore I want obviously **selectedMain** takes the **selected** value.

How to achieve this? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your own component able to emit change, and bind vaue. By default `v-model` binds to `:value` and `@change` and `@input` events but you can customize it.

In custom select component you need something like:

```
module.exports = {
    model: {
        prop: 'value',
        event: 'change'
    },
    props: [ 'options', 'value' ],
    data: function() {
        return {
            internal: null
        }
    },
    computed: {
        selected: {
            get() { return this.internal },
            set(val) {
               this.$emit('change', val)
            }
        }
    }
    watch: {
        value(newVal) {
            this.internal = newVal
        }
    }

}
```

If it's as simple as your code above (but I doubt it) the implementation can even be simpler (all done in the template):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model

```
Vue.component('base-checkbox', {
model: {
    prop: 'checked',
    event: 'change'
},
props: {
    checked: Boolean
},
template: `
    <input
    type="checkbox"
    v-bind:checked="checked"
    v-on:change="$emit('change', $event.target.checked)"
    >
`
})
```

Which you'd use in the parent template as:

```
<base-checkbox v-model="lovingVue"></base-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue has [one-way data flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow).

You can use an [event bus](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860) or state manager like [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) to guide a change in child element to a global state.